# workaround for python bytes() to handle more than range(0, 256)

Tags: python, byte

so i am looking for a bit of a workaround with the python bytes() function, as it only allows a maximum of 256. this code:

```
def mask(rawBytes):
    data = [ord(i) for i in rawBytes]
    length = len(rawBytes) + 128
    Bytes = [0x81, length]
    index = 2
    mask = os.urandom(4)
    for i in range(len(mask)):
        Bytes.insert(i + index, mask[i])        
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] ^= mask[i % 4]
        Bytes.insert(i + index + 4, data[i])
    return bytes(Bytes)
```

masks the data that i need. however, if a attempt to mask a large string, this happens:

```
>>> mask('i'*1000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    mask('i'*1000)
  File "C:/Python33/cakelibw.py", line 546, in mask
    return bytes(Bytes)
ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)
>>>
```

now is there a way to get around this? or another method that will allow for large strings?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maximum is 255 actually, check the output of `range(0, 256)`. That said, there are probably better ways to achieve what you want, like e.g. using an integer (which isn't limited) to hold a bitmask. It's not clear what you want though.

Comment: the 'i'*1000 was merely an example. i am attempting to mask data to send to a websocket server. the mask works, just not for large strings as python has a limit on the bytes().

Comment: as long as the output is the same any method will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mask(rawBytes):
    data = [ord(i) for i in rawBytes]
    length = len(rawBytes) + 128 if len(rawBytes) + 128 <= 254 else 254
    Bytes = [0x81, length]
    index = 2
    mask = os.urandom(4)
    for i in range(len(mask)):
        Bytes.insert(i + index, mask[i])        
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] ^= mask[i % 4]
        Bytes.insert(i + index + 4, data[i])
    return bytes(Bytes)
```

Comment: this is what i was going for

Comment: `length = min(254, len(data) + 128)`, which avoids use of the lateron unused `rawBytes`. `Bytes.insert` can also be replaced with `Bytes.append` or `Bytes.extend`, which would eliminate the need to compute the index manually. Then, if you really need both value and index in a loop, there is `for idx, val in enumerate(seq)`. Lastly, what's the worth of computing a `length` with an upper limit, when you append more bytes or less bytes to the actual output? This might be okay, but it looks fishy.